# Add user input when requesting API url

Tags: java, spring, api

This is a project I'm working on to basically get info on certain stocks.
The original working code is:

```
public static CommandLineRunner run(RestTemplate restTemplate) throws Exception {
    return args -> {
        Data data = restTemplate.getForObject(
                "https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/insider-transactions?symbol=CRM&token=c683tuqad3iagio36uj0", Data.class);
        log.info(data.toString());
        System.out.println(data);
        
        ResponseEntity<List<String>> peersResponse =
                restTemplate.exchange("https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/peers?symbol=CRM&token=c683tuqad3iagio36uj0",
                            HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>() {
                    });
        List<String> peers = peersResponse.getBody();
        System.out.println(peers);
    };
}
```

And what I'm trying to do is to add a user "input" to add in between the URL to get info on a stock.

There are several issues at hand here:

1. I know CommandLineRunner starts right away when you run the app. What is a good way to make my app wait for an "input" from the user?
2. And secondly, to use that "input" within the API url to request the data?

I am not sure if I am explaining myself correctly and I hope by showing my original code and the code that I want to achieve will make it easier for any experts out there to understand. Thanks for any help!

What I want to do:

```
public static CommandLineRunner run(RestTemplate restTemplate) throws Exception {
        return args -> {
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            Data data = restTemplate.getForObject(
                    "https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/insider-transactions?symbol=" + input + "&token=c683tuqad3iagio36uj0", Data.class);
            log.info(data.toString());
            System.out.println(data);
            
            ResponseEntity<List<String>> peersResponse =
                    restTemplate.exchange("https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/peers?symbol=" + input + "&token=c683tuqad3iagio36uj0",
                                HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>() {
                        });
            List<String> peers = peersResponse.getBody();
            System.out.println(peers);
        };
    }
```

I just modified my code to correctly accept "input" to the API URL, as well as showing more of my codes:

```
public class StocksQueryApplication {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StocksQueryApplication.class);
    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StocksQueryApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder.build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public static CommandLineRunner run(RestTemplate restTemplate) throws Exception {
        return args -> {
            Data data = restTemplate.getForObject(
                    "https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/insider-transactions?symbol=" + input + "&token=c683tuqad3iagio36uj0", Data.class);
            log.info(data.toString());
            System.out.println(data);
            
            ResponseEntity<List<String>> peersResponse =
                    restTemplate.exchange("https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/peers?symbol=" + input + "&token=c683tuqad3iagio36uj0",
                                HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>() {
                        });
            List<String> peers = peersResponse.getBody();
            System.out.println(peers);
        };
    }
}
```

What's left is just to make CommandLineRunner wait for a user "input" then run. But I can't seem to figure out how to do that.

Comment: What about using a command line argument for user input?

Comment: @tgdavies Thanks for the response! I am still a little confused, can you elaborate?

Comment: My intuition is that I should not be using CommandLineRunner since it starts right away when I run the app, but I do not know of any other way to log out the data I get from the API call.

Comment: You can use `Scanner` within your `CommandLineRunner` to read input.

Comment: So what you're saying is that my second block of codes is correct? So what's left is to make CommandLineRunner wait for a user input so that it will know what "input" is